# random corrupted data in serial Arduino

Tags: serialization, arduino

I have issue to read serial data from Arduino Uno in UWP C#. Sometimes when I start app I get corrupted data.
But in arduino monitor always is good.
Corrupted data is like this:

```
57 
5
```

But should be 557.

Arduino codes:

```
String digx, digx2, digx3, digx1 ;
void setup() {
  delay(500); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A1);
  sensorValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 1024, 0, 999);

  digx1 =  String(sensorValue % 10);
  digx2 =  String((sensorValue / 10) % 10);
  digx3 =  String((sensorValue / 100) % 10);
  digx = (digx3 + digx2 + digx1);
 
  Serial.println(digx);
  Serial.flush();
  delay(100);
}
```

And windows universal codes:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public DataReader dataReader;
    public SerialDevice serialPort;
    private string data;

    private async void InitializeConnection()
    {
        var aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(0x2341, 0x0043);
        var info = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

        serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(info[0].Id);
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
        serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;
        serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
        serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        dataReader = new DataReader(serialPort.InputStream);
        while (true)
        {
            await ReadAsync();
        }
    }

    private async Task ReadAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            uint readBufferLength = 5;
            dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
            //dataReader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;

            var loadAsyncTask = dataReader.LoadAsync(readBufferLength).AsTask();
            var ReadAsyncBytes = await loadAsyncTask;

            if (ReadAsyncBytes > 0)
            {
                data = dataReader.ReadString(ReadAsyncBytes);
                serialValue.Text = data;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

My idea was if it happened, Program skip that data. I tried different buffer length but more or less than 5 will always receive incorrect.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your Windows code has no support for the framing the Arduino uses. The Arduino writes lines and the Windows code reads chunks of five bytes. That's a framing mismatch. If the Arduino writes lines, the Windows code *must* read lines. Otherwise, it has no idea where the messages end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods that can fix your problem.

**Method1: Make your UART communication robust**

That there is no chance of an error but this is a tricky and time-consuming task in the case of windows software communicating with Arduino.

But still have some tricks which can help you because I have tried them and some of them work but please don't ask for the reason why it works.

1. Change your UART baud rate from 9600 to something else (mine if works perfect at 38400).
2. Replace `Serial.begin(9600);` to `Serial.begin(38400,SERIAL_8N1)`where 8 is data bit, 1 is stop bit and N is parity none in SERIAL_8N1. And you can also try different settings in data bit, stop bit, and parity.  check [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial.Begin)
3. don't send data after converting it into a string `Serial.println(digx);`. Send data in form of bytes array use `Serial.write(digx,len);`. check [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/write/)

**Method2: Add CRC Packet**

At the end of each data packet and then send. When it reaches the windows software first fetch all UART data then calculate CRC from that data and then just compare calculated CRC and received CRC.If CRC matches then the data is correct and if not then ignore data and wait for new data.

you can check for CRC calculation its direct formula base implement and for little head start check this [library by vinmenn.](https://github.com/vinmenn/Crc16)

Comment: Thanks I will check and report.

Comment: Which CRC are you sending is it CRC16

Comment: Yes, Using `getCrc()`. And also in first method that you advised me the problem is that when arduino writes the array I'll get the 3 digits separately. @dharmik

Comment: Check this post for an C# CRC16 check function    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953396/calculating-crc16-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

I used two things to fix the problem,

**1.** In Windows codes added `SerialDevice.IsDataTerminalReadyEnabled = true` property to read bytes with correct order. From Microsoft docs
Here's [a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice.readtimeout?view=winrt-19041)!

**2.** As dharmik helped, I used array and send it with `Serial.write(array, arrayLength)` in Arduino and read them with `dataReader.ReadBytes(array[])` and right buffer size in Windows app.

And result is so stable even with much lower Delays.