# CRC-16/X-25 Calculation

Tags: c#, crc16

I'm searching to calculate CRC-16 for concox VTS. After search a lot I've got several formula, lookup table, CRC32.net library etc and tried them. But didn't get the actual result which I've wanted.

For example, when I use crc32.net library :

```
byte[] data = { 11, 01, 03, 51, 51, 00, 94, 10, 95, 20, 20, 08, 25, 81, 00, 23 };
UInt32 crcOut = Crc32Algorithm.ComputeAndWriteToEnd(data);
Console.WriteLine(crcOut.ToString());
```

It returns : 3232021645

But actually it should return : 90DD

I've tried another example too but they also did not return proper value.

Edit :

Here is the RAW data from Device :

```
{78}{78}{11}{01}{03}{51}{51}{00}{94}{10}{95}{20}{20}{08}{25}{81}{00}{23}{90}{DD}{0D}{0A}
```

When split by following data sheet, it looks like -

```
{78}{78}    =   Start Bit
{11}        =   Packet Length(17) = (01 + 12 + 02 + 02) =  Decimal 17 = Hexadecimal 11      
{01}        =   Protocol No
{03}{51}{51}{00}{94}{10}{95}{20}    =   TerminalID  =   0351510094109520
{20}{08}    =   Model Identification Code
{25}{81}    =   Time Zone Language
{00}{23}    =   Information Serial No
{90}{DD}    =   Error Check (CRC : Packet Length to Information Serial No)
{0D}{0A}    =   Stop Bit
```

They told in error check it need CRC from Packet Length to Information Serial No. To make reply this packet I also need to make a data packet with CRC code.

I've found an online calculator from below link. The data match with CRC-16/X-25.

Now I need to calculate it by C# code.

https://crccalc.com/?crc=11,%2001,%2003,%2051,%2051,%2000,%2094,%2010,%2095,%2020,%2020,%2008,%2025,%2081,%2000,%2023&method=CRC-16/X-25&datatype=hex&outtype=0

Waiting for your reply.

Thanks

Comment: Did you already see these question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860356/how-to-generate-a-crc-16-from-c-sharp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953396/calculating-crc16-in-c-sharp

Comment: Tried, but did not match my requirement. I'll send a byte array any it should return CRC-16/X-25 calculative data.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like CRC32.net is actually computing the CRC-32C, using the Castagnoli polynomial. That's also what the Intel crc32 instructions aid in computing.

Comment: I've found from an article that this CRC32.NET can also calculate CRC16 format data. But I can't calculate CRC-16 from this library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CRC-16 you assert that you need in your comment (which needs to be in your question) is the [CRC-16/X-25](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/16.htm#crc.cat.crc-16-ibm-sdlc). On your data, that CRC gives `0xcac0`, not `0x90dd`.

In fact, none of the documented CRC-16's listed in that catalog produce `0x90dd` for your data. You need to provide a reference for the CRC that you need, and how you determined that `0x90dd` is the expected result for that data.

*Update for updated question:*

The bytes you provided in your example data are in *decimal*:

```
byte[] data = { 11, 01, 03, 51, 51, 00, 94, 10, 95, 20, 20, 08, 25, 81, 00, 23 };
```

That is completely wrong, since, based on the actual data message data in your updated question that you want the CRC for, those digits must be interpreted as *hexadecimal*. (Just by chance, none of those numbers have hexadecimal digits in `a`..`f`.) To represent that test vector in your code correctly, it needs to be:

```
byte[] data = { 0x11, 0x01, 0x03, 0x51, 0x51, 0x00, 0x94, 0x10, 0x95, 0x20, 0x20, 0x08, 0x25, 0x81, 0x00, 0x23 };
```

This computes the CRC-16/X-25:

```
ushort crc16_x25(byte[] data, int len) {
    ushort crc = 0xffff;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc ^= data[i];
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = (crc & 1) != 0 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0x8408 : crc >> 1;
    }
    return ~crc;
}
```

Comment: Please visit the following link : 
https://crccalc.com/?crc=11,%2001,%2003,%2051,%2051,%2000,%2094,%2010,%2095,%2020,%2020,%2008,%2025,%2081,%2000,%2023&method=CRC-16/X-25&datatype=hex&outtype=0

After submit data See on "CRC-16/X-25" section. I need to calculate this value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I modified it from this example https://gist.github.com/andresv/4611897 (Thank you Andresv)

```
uint16_t x25crc16(unsigned char *data_p, uint16_t lenght) {
    uint16_t crc = 0xFFFF;
    uint32_t data;
    uint16_t crc16_table[] = {
            0x0000, 0x1081, 0x2102, 0x3183,
            0x4204, 0x5285, 0x6306, 0x7387,
            0x8408, 0x9489, 0xa50a, 0xb58b,
            0xc60c, 0xd68d, 0xe70e, 0xf78f
    };

    while(lenght--){
        crc = ( crc >> 4 ) ^ crc16_table[(crc & 0xf) ^ (*data_p & 0xf)];
        crc = ( crc >> 4 ) ^ crc16_table[(crc & 0xf) ^ (*data_p++ >> 4)];
    }

    data = crc;
    return (~crc);
}
```

Test with an array of characters

```
int main()
{
    uint8_t ascii_arr[9] =  {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    uint16_t checksum = 0;
    printf("\"%s\"\n", ascii_arr);

    checksum = x25crc16(ascii_arr, 9);
    printf("CRC-16 X-25: 0x%x\n", checksum );
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
"123456789"
CRC-16 X-25: 0x906e
```

You can compare with this online CRC calculator https://crccalc.com/?crc=123456789&method=CRC-16/X-25&datatype=ascii&outtype=0

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are wrong but i tried input in crccalc web page and in one app that i use for calculate crc 16-X25

11 01 03 51 51 00 94 10 95 29 29 08 25 81 00 23

and both gives me 0xF497

I'll share you my code in C

Hope it helps

```
uint16_t CRC_crc16(const uint8_t *pData, uint16_t num_bytes)
{  
  static volatile uint16_t crc; 
  static volatile uint8_t i, byte, temp;
    
    crc = 0xffff;    // Reset crc
    do 
    { 
        for (i = 0, byte = *pData++; i < 8; i++, byte >>= 1) 
        { 
            temp = (uint8_t) ((uint8_t) crc & (uint8_t) 0x01); 
            crc >>= 1; 
            if (temp ^ (byte & 0x01)) 
            crc ^= 0x8408; 
        }
    } 
    while (--num_bytes); 
  
  crc = ~((crc << 8) | (crc >> 8));
  return crc;
}
```

[crc16 X25 Calc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11vJc.png)